# Split a string in list array

Tags: java, android

How can I split each of the sentence in the arraylist? what i'm trying to make is, a different set of sentence to be splitted and shuffle, and student will arrange it in correct order

```
public class QuestionActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int presCounter = 0;
    private int maxpresCounter;

    private List<QuestionModel1> list;

    TextView textScreen, textQuestion, textTitle;
    Button submitBtn;


    @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);
        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        submitBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);


        list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new QuestionModel1("The kids are playing"));
        list.add(new QuestionModel1("The kids are sleeping"));
        list.add(new QuestionModel1("The kids are dancing"));
        

        keys=shuffleArray(keys);
        for (String key : keys){
            addView(((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutParent)), key, ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)));
        }
        maxpresCounter= keys.length;

    }
```

I can only try one

```
private String sentence="The kids are playing";
private String[] keys=sentence.split(" ");
```

QuestionModel Class

```
public class QuestionModel1 {
    private String sentence;

    public QuestionModel1(String sentence) {
        this.sentence = sentence;
    }

    public String getSentence() {
        return sentence;
    }

    public void setSentence(String sentence) {
        this.sentence = sentence;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add an [mcve]

Comment: Can you provide your QuestionModel1 class, or at least a part of it?  What are the getter methods of the class called?

Comment: @BigBeef i added the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for (QuestionModel1 questionModel1 : list) {
        String sentence = questionModel1.getSentence();
        String[] keys = sentence.split(" ");
        // do what you need below for each key.
        // shuffleArray(keys); <--- A stab at what you need ??? 
    }
```

Something like this?

Comment: ill try this one, i think i can almost figure it out

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming we have the following array list:

```
List<QuestionModel1> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new QuestionModel1("The kids are playing"));
list.add(new QuestionModel1("The kids are sleeping"));
list.add(new QuestionModel1("The kids are dancing"));
```

you could split it with the following snippet, assuming you're using at least Java 8

```
List<List<String>> newList = list.stream()
                .map(item -> Arrays.asList(item.getSentence().split(" ")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and this would yield the following `List<List<String>>` as a result

```
[[The, kids, are, playing],[The, kids, are, sleeping],[The, kids, are, dancing]]
```

Now, if you just want the words in one long list (including duplicates), you could just add one additional `.flatMap(...)` operation

```
List<String> keys = list.stream()
                .map(item -> Arrays.asList(item.getSentence().split(" ")))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which would yield the following `List<String>` as a result:

```
[The, kids, are, playing, The, kids, are, sleeping, The, kids, are, dancing]
```

This isn't the only approach (you could use `.reduce(...)` instead of `.flatMap(...)`, for example), but it should fit your problem.

Comment: and how can i implement that in this

for (String key : keys){
            addView(((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutParent)), key, ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)));
        }